# How to run method with parameters in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, methods, parameters

How do I create a method in objective-c where I can run the method with different parameters each time. For example I want to be able to do something like this:

```
int thisMethod (int thisInt; NSString *thisString) {
    int anotherInt = thisInt+2;
    self.thisLabel.stringValue = thisString;
    return 0;
}
```

So in this code, I want to run thisMethod with two parameters that can be used in the method.
i.e:

```
thisMethod(10; @"String");
```

Do I need to use a structure like this:

```
- (int) thisMethod:(id)sender{
    //code here
}
```

If so, how do I use the parameters?

Comment: Read [Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Yeah, you'd better read some tutorials.  There's a heck of a lot more to Objective-C than just understanding the funky call syntax.

Comment: BTW - your first `thisMethod` isn't a method, it's a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (int)thisMethodWithInt:(int)thisInt andString:(NSString *)thisString {
    int anotherInt = thisInt+2;
    self.thisLabel.stringValue = thisString;
    return 0;
}
```

Calling the Method then would look like this:

```
[self thisMethodWithInt:3 andString:@"My Super String"];
```

What you are describing is a c function and not a objective-c one..

Comment: This would also need to be declared in a class interface with `thisLabel` as a declared `@property`

Comment: that is right.. I don't know his setup.. of course you could also pass a UI/NSLabel as parameter if you don't have that

Answer (score 0):

You would have to pass the label object too, because self has no meaning in a C function. In Objective-C it's a hidden parameter that is passed to every method, but in a C function you have to pass it yourself (and use commas, instead of semicolons):

```
int thisMethod (int thisInt, NSString *thisString, id object) {
    int anotherInt = thisInt+2;
    object.thisLabel.stringValue = thisString;
    return 0;
}
```

You probably have to explicitly set the type though, instead of using `id`, or the compiler will complain.

Again, use commas to separate arguments:

```
thisMethod(10, @"String", self);
```